# How to interpret LISA clustering maps?

Tags: r, clustering, data-visualization, spatial

I have produced a LISA clustering map showing the types of significant clustering of the proportion of part-time workers in London:

[image: LISA clustering map]

However, as I understand it, 'low-high' describes an area of low value surrounded by areas of high values. How can this be the case if this 'low-high' area is directly next to a 'low-low' area (low value surrounded by low values)?

The same is the case for 'high-low' clustering directly next to 'high-high' clustering.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the weight matrix you are using and hence each area in the London is associated with a set of neighbors.
The LISA cluster will look at the value of the given area and the values of its neighbors and decides if it corresponds to a bright blue, pale blue, pale red, bright red or grey colour.

"The strongly colored regions are therefore those that contribute significantly to a positive global spatial autocorrelation outcome, while paler colors contribute significantly to a negative autocorrelation outcome." This means that the pale colours are surrounded by dissimilar values that occur near one another.